# Можно употреблять "конечно", "безусловно" вместе?

Tags: пунктуация

Конечно, безусловно, мне не всё нравится.

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, что такая фраза некорректна, так как эти вводные слова являются синонимами и раскрывают одну и ту же тему - степень уверенности говорящего:

КОНЕЧНО. II. вводн. сл. Разумеется, несомненно.

БЕЗУСЛОВНО. II. вводн. сл. Разумеется, конечно.

Answer (score 1):

Лучше использовать в данном предложении одно из вводных слов, ибо по смыслу они похожи.

Но рядом эти два слова вполне могут быть, например в случае экспрессивной реплики-согласия, ср.: Да, конечно, безусловно!